# How to use a string variable as the index of the Workbook object?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use a string variable as the index of a `Workbook` object.

It is giving me the error:

> "Subscript out of range".

I will let the user choose where the "base" file will come from and store the path plus the file name in the variable `wb_or`.

```
Sub search_data()

'
Dim wb_origin As Workbook   'Planilha de origem dos dados
Dim ws_origin As Worksheet  'Aba da planilha de origem dos dados
Dim wb_or   As String      'Variável para armazenar o caminho da planilha de origem

'Definir nomes e locais
MsgBox "Selecionar o Arquivo de origem dos dados."
'Abrir um navegador para selecionar o arquivo gerado pelo ERP
wb_or = Application.GetOpenFilename("All XLSX files (*.xlsx*), *.xlsx", , "Test")
Set wb_origin = Application.Workbooks(wb_or)
Set ws_origin = wb_origin.Sheets(1)
        
End Sub
```

Comment: `Set wb_origin = Workbooks.Open(wb_or)`

Comment: `GetOpenFilename` doesn't open the selected file - you have to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Rafael,
I believe you want to retrieve a folder reference ("I will let the user chose where the "base" file will come from...") into wb_or rather than a file reference thus you should use a function like this:

```
Function FolderSelector(ByVal zBaseFolder As String) As String

'Arguments: zBaseFold - Initial default folder to display
'Returns:   Selected folder WITH OUT the trailing \

    Dim fd             As FileDialog
    
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 
    If (zBaseFolder = "") Then zBaseFolder = "C:\"
    If (Not (Right(zBaseFolder, 1)) = "\") Then zBaseFolder = zBaseFolder + "\"

    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = zBaseFolder  '*** Make sure you have the trailing \ ***
        .Show
        If (.SelectedItems.Count = 1) Then FolderSelector = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With 'FD

End Function  'FolderSelector
```

You'd call it like this:

```
wb_or = FolderSelector("") '*** You can set a starting location between the "". ***
If (wb_or = "") Then
  '*** Process missing value here, i.e. user doesn't make selection or presses Cancel ***
End If  
    
End Function   'FolderSelector
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I think I could have written better my question because what I need is not only where the file is, but I need the name of the file as well, for example:  `C:\Users\Roberto\Desktop\teste_fonte.xlsx` In order to set the Workbook variable, `wb_origin`